# Vote for Exception for Not Closing

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions, score

Yes, we all know that there are many questions asked that met the requirements for closing the question as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

I agreed that some questions are totally "off topic".

But in some very rare cases, even though the question totally fits the requirements for closing or the definition of "off-topic", the question has a very high value as the answers gathered will truly benefit all the developers.

And sometimes, a closed question continues to receive lots of votes, or is highly upvoted already.

The number of votes these questions have already speaks for itself - it is a highly valuable question even if it is off-topic.

Closing a highly upvoted question makes no sense.

So, can we have another option for "voting for exception".

Lets say, maybe at 20 votes or 35 votes.

Example: [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Sometimes old, off topic but highly popular questions are given a historical lock by moderators. This sounds like what you are describing

Comment: Closed <> Deleted.  Closing is the path to deletion, but generally speaking, valuable closed questions (as judged by voting and # of answers) never are deleted (or at least rarely) regardless of the close reason.  So I don't get the purpose here.  Do you have specific examples of posts you think should be saved from deletion that are in danger (or have been deleted)

Comment: @RichardTingle sounds rather like the notice under the too broad subjective resource recommendation question tagged C++ and somewhere along the top of the top question list.

Comment: Closed != deleted

Comment: Example please!(I've never seen such questions)

Comment: @Oded Yes, but unable to add more answers.

Comment: Yes. That's the meaning of closed. Why should it remain as if nothing if it is blatantly off-topic (however popular)?

Comment: Also note that closed questions can be reopened the same way they are closed...

Comment: Coem on, how is this a duplicate of "How can I encourage Stack Overflow to rein in the 'subjective' vigilantes?" (that's the question marked as original to the one @gnat linked to)

Comment: __This is a specific feature-request__, not a discussion, so it's not even a dupe.

Comment: @LanceRoberts the dupe and the dupe of the dupe has enough info and a decent answer.

Comment: @user689 I have added an example in my question.

Comment: @Oded I have added an example in my question. Take that as example, if someone has some awesome C# Excel library, he/she was unable to share.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, I have added an example in the question.

Comment: @mjb ok, so why does that question need new answers?  It has 34 of them.  And most of the answers are just links to tools, which is likely why it was closed to begin with.  And it is not going anywhere (in terms of deletion), so it will be valuable for people in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Problem with keeping highly-upvoted questions open, even if they don't meet today's standards, is with experts.

Silly, simple or stupid but amusing questions can easily get a lot of upvotes, if they happen to appear at the right time, right place. But the power of Stack Exchange is in experts. The ones that answer 10, 20, 50 times more often than ask. Allowing poor questions to dilute this site would drive experienced answerers away, and that would be bad, especially for askers.

Comment: I mean come on, you don't visit Stack to *ask* question, you visit to have your question *answered*. Questions are useless on their own, all their usefulness comes from answers (both posted and potential). It is important not to forget this.

Comment: I have added an example in my question. Take that as example, if someone has some awesome C# Excel library, he/she was unable to share.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that silly, simple or stupid but amusing questions should get lost from stackoverflow. Allowing idiot question in stackoverflow is just polluting stackoverflow and making my brain becomes short circuit.

Comment: @mjb if someone posts "question" to share his work, then he is doing it for wrong reasons. He should contact ads@stackexchange.com instead.